# No C terminal, where to tie in smart thermostat

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

Trying to figure out how to connect the Ecobee adapter. I can follow up with more pics and info / questions (like connecting via the transformer), but everything I’ve read up on has led me to this question. What is up with my AC wire?

The AC wire splits red and white. The Red connects to a yellow wire which goes to the thermostat.

The white connects to a grey. This grey goes to a screw above the capacitor. My first reaction was, “Is this just grounding?” Which doesn’t seem great. But attached to that screw there is also a green wire. This green wire goes to the box on the door of the furnace that has the spring sensor that turns off the furnace if you remove the front panels (so the main power I assume).

So maybe this screw above the capacitor isn’t just for grounding, but is actually connecting to the green which is returning? And if so, could I tie in my C wire into where the AC white and grey wires connect?

*Updated* added pics of transformer, were the wires from the transformer connect to, and the wiring diagram from the furnace panel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Draw out all the wires. The gray appears to be used as a ground which is maybe goofy but works.

Comment: Thanks @KMJ added the wiring diagram.

Answer (score 1):

### Land C on that screw, yeah

Your air handler's wiring diagram calls for landing C (B in their nomenclature) on the chassis, so yeah, that's just a chassis ground screw.  You may wish to crimp an non-insulated spade lug of the appropriate size onto the end of your C wire for this, by the way.